# GUI for joining AD after installation - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: active-directory

as we know, we can join AD domain in an installation process, but is there GUI to do this after install? like its super easy on Mac and Windows?

If there is no GUI, how can i make a request about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen one. Thing is... the software used on the Linux end consists of 1 command and 1 configuration file and is almost only used on a server. That totally negates the need for a graphical front end.

All of the tools to connect are based around command line.

- [realm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/realm.8.html) does it like this after configuration:

  ```
  realm join --user=[domain user account] [domain name]
  ```

Not a lot a GUI can do better than that.

If you want a GUI you probably need to make one yourself; it is a Redhat project so not Ubuntu nor Canonical.

Comment: Thank U, still GUI would be good as it is in other main OSes )

Answer (score 1):

It is built in to the new os setup now, btw. There is equally a gui post-install now.

https://github.com/ubuntu/adsys/blob/main/doc/02.-Prerequisites.md

### Prerequisites and installation

In order to use Group Policies on an Ubuntu client, the  first thing to do is, of course, to join the computer to an Active  Directory domain.

There are 2 ways to join an AD domain:

1. At installation time with the Ubuntu Desktop installer.
2. After installation, by manually setting up the connection to AD.

#### Joining Active Directory domain

##### Joining at installation time

Joining during installation is only supported by the  Ubuntu Desktop graphical installer Ubiquity. So, start an installation  of Ubuntu Desktop as you would usually do and proceed to the page **"Who are you?"**. Enter user and computer name information.

> *Note about the host name:*
>
> *In order to set and resolve the host name properly, you must enter the **Fully Qualified Domain Name** (FQDN) of the machine in the field "Your computer's name". For example, `host01.example.com` instead of only the host name `host01`.*
>
> *After installation you can check if it is correct with the command `hostname` and `hostname -f` which must return the name of the machine (`host01`) and the full name of the machine with the domain (`host01.example.com`) respectively.*

Check the box **"Use Active Directory"** and click **"Continue"** to proceed with next step **"Configure Active Directory"**.

On this page you can enter the address of the Active  Directory controller and credentials of the user allowed to add machines to the domain.

You can verify that the server is reachable by pressing **"Test Connection"**.

Once all the information has been entered and is valid, press **"Continue"** to proceed with the remaining usual steps of the installation.

At the end of the installation you can reboot the machine and you are ready to log in as a user of the domain on first boot.

If anything goes wrong with the join process during  installation, you will be notified by a dialog box. You can still reboot the machine, log in as the administrator user of the machine (ie the  user you entered in the page **"Who are you?"**) and troubleshoot the issue. The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd) provides instructions to perform such troubleshooting.

##### Joining manually using SSSD

The purpose of this document is to describe how to operate ADSys. So we won’t do an in depth description of the operations to  manually configure a connection to Active Directory from an Ubuntu  Client.

Authentication of Ubuntu against the Active Directory  server requires to configure SSSD and Kerberos. SSSD will then retrieve  the credentials and the initial security policy of the `Default Domain Policy`.

All these operations are perfectly described in the [Ubuntu Server Guide “Service - SSSD”](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd) and the White Paper [How to integrate Ubuntu Desktop with Active Directory](https://ubuntu.com/engage/microsoft-active-directory).

##### Joining manually using Winbind

In addition to SSSD, ADSys supports using Winbind as a backend. The easiest way to join a domain using Winbind is to use the `realmd` utility, as described in the [Samba - Active Directory](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-active-directory) guide.

ADSys uses SSSD as a default backend, so Winbind has to be opted into explicitly via the following config option in `adsys.yaml`:

```
ad_backend: winbind
```

In addition, Winbind requires additional dependencies to  be installed. On Ubuntu-based systems they can be installed by executing the following command, prior to ADSys:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install winbind krb5-user
```

#### Installing ADSys

**ADSys** is not currently installed by default on Ubuntu desktop. This must be done manually by the local administrator of the machine.

To do so, log in on first boot, update the repositories and install **ADSys**. On Ubuntu-based systems this can be accomplished with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adsys
```

Reboot then to allow the machine to do its policy refresh.

#### Logging in as a user of the domain

To log in as a user of the domain, press the link **"Not listed?"** in the greeter. Then enter the username followed by the password.

##### SSSD

By default, there is no default domain configured in SSSD. You have to enter the full user name with one of the forms: `USER@DOMAIN.COM`, `USER@DOMAIN` or `DOMAIN/USER`.

On the first log in the user's home directory is created.

All of this (default domain, default path for home directories, default shell, etc.) is configurable in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.

##### Winbind

If Winbind is used as a backend, the account can be specified in one of the following forms: `USER@DOMAIN.COM`, `USER@DOMAIN` or `DOMAIN\\USER`.

For the home directory to be created automatically on login, the `pam_mkhomedir` module can be enabled:

```
sudo pam-auth-update --enable mkhomedir
```

Options such as the home directory path template, shell and others can be tweaked in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and are documented in the [`smb.conf(5)`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) manpage.